# Server not receiving messages from client

Tags: python, sockets, server, client, python-multithreading

Hi This is my first post here. I am making a chatroom in Python using sockets and I have written the code for the server and client side. I am successful in establishing a connection between the server and the clients but I can't send any messages. The client provides a password and username through terminal and the server check if the password is correct and only then the client can send messages. I have not yet implemented the password check yet but the messages are still not being sent. I have made sure I am encoding and decoding correctly. I have also implemented threading to allow multiple users. Here is the server side code:

```
import socket
import threading
import sys 


#TODO: Implement all code for your server here


#usernames = []

def broadcast(message):
    for client in clients:
        client.send(message)

def handle_client(client_socket, client_address):
    try:
        
        password = client_socket.recv(1024).decode()
        username = client_socket.recv(1024).decode()
        print("user: " + username)
        clients.append(client_socket)
        while True:
            message = username + " joined the chatroom"
            print(message)
            broadcast(message.encode())

            message = client_socket.recv(1024).decode()
            if (message != ":Exit"):
                print(f"{username}: {message}")
                broadcast(message.encode())
            else:
                print(f"{username} left the chatroom")
                clients.remove(client_socket)
                client_socket.close()
                message = username + " left the chatroom"
                broadcast(message.encode())
                break
    except:
        client_socket.close()       
        
def receive():
    while True:
        client_socket, client_address = server.accept()
        print(client_socket)
        client_thread = threading.Thread(target=handle_client, args=(client_socket, client_address))
        client_thread.start()

# Use sys.stdout.flush() after print statemtents

if __name__ == "__main__":
    HOST = '127.0.0.1'
    #PORT = int(sys.argv[1])

    server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    server.bind((HOST, 10001))
    server.listen(5)

    clients = []
    print("server is listening")
    receive()
```

Here is the client side:

```
import socket
import threading
import sys 



#TODO: Implement a client that connects to your server to chat with other clients here

HOST = '127.0.0.1'
#PORT = int(sys.argv[1])

client_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

client_socket.connect((HOST, 10001))

username = sys.argv[1]
password = sys.argv[2]

client_socket.send(password.encode())
client_socket.send(username.encode())
reply = client_socket.recv(1024).decode()
print(reply)

def receive():
    while True:
        try:
            message = client_socket.recv(1024).decode()
            if message:
                print(message)
        except:
            continue

def write():
    while True:
        message = input()
        if message == ":Exit":
            client_socket.send(message.encode())
            client_socket.close()
            break
        else:
            client_socket.send(message.encode())

receive_thread = threading.Thread(target=receive)
receive_thread.start()

write_thread = threading.Thread(target=write)
write_thread.start()
# Use sys.stdout.flush() after print statemtents

if __name__ == "__main__":
    pass
```

I have tried asking my TAs but they were of no help :(.

Comment: First thing I notice is that in the client you are taking arguments 1 and 2 but not 0. This probably isnt a big deal.

Comment: Its possible that if you dont have 3 arguments, that could be the issue with your client.

Comment: **TCP is not message-based**.  You cannot assume one send equates to one receive of the same data.  You get the bytes in the order sent, but two sends might be one or more receives.  Buffer data and extract complete messages.  For text-based messages, newlines can be used to indicate the end of a message.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are taking the second and third arguments instead of first and second. Thus if you do not pass 3 arguments with the third being the password then the client will not have a password to send.